# After copying a data frame to_datetime function fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am copying data from one dataframe to the other frame.  In the new dataframe I want to set the `TimeStamp` column to use the dateformat `2020-05-29` But I am getting an error.

```
ls2_df= ls_df[(ls_df.Manager == "David H") & (ls_df.Store == 4007)]
ls2_df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(ls2_df.TimeStamp)
```

Gives the following error.

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: ls2_df= ls_df[(ls_df.Manager == "David H") & (ls_df.Store == 4007)].copy(), add copy at the end

Comment: I added the `.copy()` however the timestamp is still not formatting to `2020-05-29` like the `parse_dates`